# store latitude and longitude in ios address book

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

Can **latitude** and **longitude** be added to a record in an `iOS` address book?

My app wants to display nearby contacts on a map.  I know how to get the latitude/longitude from an address.  I do not know how to save them so I can avoid repeated lookups

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a latitude-and-longitude address to a contact in your iOS address book.  It takes one extra step to view the map pin from that address, but it works.

Open an existing or new Contact, and create a new address. Under Street, put in the latitude and longitude, with a comma between but no blank space.
Leave everything else empty: city, state, and so on.  It will force you to pick a country, so either just leave the default, or if you want, you can select the country that corresponds to the coordinates, though it really doesn't matter.

For example, you could enter:

•   Street:  48.8582,2.2945 
  •   Country: France   (or any country)

(For locations South of the equator or East of the Greenwich meridian, add a minus sign: e.g., -17.53655,-149.56832).

Save the address.

To go to the location in Apple maps, open the Contact and click the latitude/longitude address.  This will take you to Apple maps.  Don't wait for the map to come up, because if you wait the pin will be dead center in whatever country is listed.  Instead, while it's thinking, just go to the address bar at the top and edit out the country so that only the lat/long is left and hit Search.  This time, the pin will go directly to the correct latitude/longitude location.  If you want Google maps, just copy/paste the lat/long into Google maps.

The example shown above should put you right at the Eiffel Tower.  Bon voyage!

Comment: You should replace data like country etc. with `XX` or something other

Answer (score 0):

In iPhone native address book it's not possible to store. But you can do one thing, you can store info of the user in **SQLite database** in your app along with **lat lon** and if you want some **synchronization** functionality then you can create **web-service** which will update your SQLite database as per your logic.

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this may be not possible to add **`latitude`** and **`longitude`** value to `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`. but if you want to find distance between two Contact then you can find it from contacts's address or add your **`latitude`** and **`longitude`** value into **database** and use 2 option of mine .

There are two way for find location by address

**1)** [How to get street address from ABPeoplePickerNavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329006/how-to-get-street-address-from-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller)

**2)** use [reverseGeocodeLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:) and also check this my answer [CLLocationManager not getting City name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270527/cllocationmanager-not-getting-city-name/15270655#15270655) this is helpful for you.